# Filtering and collecting different elements from two arrays using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to combine two arrays using Combine in Swift and filter out the elements that are different between them. I want to collect these different elements into another array using a PassthroughSubject.

Here's my code:

```
import Combine

let subject1 = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()
let subject2 = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

subject1.send([4, 5, 6, 8])
subject2.send([4, 5, 7, 9])
subject1.send(completion: .finished)
subject2.send(completion: .finished)

let filteredSubject = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

Publishers.CombineLatest(subject1, subject2)
    .map { array1, array2 in
        zip(array1, array2)
    }
    .filter { element1, element2 in
        element1 != element2
    }
    .map { element1, _ in
        element1
    }
    .sink { filteredElement in
        filteredSubject.send(filteredElement)
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)

filteredSubject
    .sink { filteredElements in
        print("Filtered Elements:", filteredElements)
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

I expect this code to combine subject1 and subject2, filter out the elements that are different between them, and collect these different elements into filteredSubject using a sink. However, it's not printing anything for the filtered elements. What am I missing in my code to achieve the desired result?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Set to simplify the comparisons:

```
import UIKit


import Combine

let subject1 = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()
let subject2 = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

let filteredSubject = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

subject1.combineLatest(subject2)
    .map { array1, array2 -> Set<Int> in
        var set = Set(array1)
        return set.subtracting(array2)
    }.sink { filteredSubject.send( Array<Int>($0)) }

filteredSubject
    .sink { filteredElements in
        print("Filtered Elements:", filteredElements)
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)


subject1.send([4, 5, 6, 8])
subject2.send([4, 5, 7, 9])
subject1.send(completion: .finished)
subject2.send(completion: .finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you send elements before subscribing to these subjects:

```swift
subject1.send([4, 5, 6, 8])
subject2.send([4, 5, 7, 9])

// Publishers.CombineLatest(subject1, subject2)

// send here
```

So your `CombineLatest` function already sees the finished subjects. Try subscribing at first and then only send items.